# How to overlay two ReliefPlots, or other graphics

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is it possible to overlay two or more graphics in Mathematica, if the graphics are generated by functions such as ReliefPlot or DensityPlot, using Opacity to control the appearance?

For example:

```
a = ReliefPlot[
        Table[i + Sin[i^2 + j^2], {i, -4, 4, .03}, {j, -4, 4, .03}], ImageSize -> 100]
b = ReliefPlot[
        Table[i + Sin[i^3 + j^3], {i, -4, 4, .03}, {j, -4, 4, .03}], ImageSize -> 100]
Show[a,b]
```

[image]

combines the two, but I can't work out how to insert an Opacity command anywhere here such that both are visible. The documentation states that these functions accept the same options as Graphics ("ReliefPlot has the same options as Graphics, with the following additions and changes:"), but I don't understand how to control the graphics... (And I may be confused about the difference between graphics options and directives, as well.)

Enlightenment - and less opacity - very welcome!

Edit: Wow, you guys are quicker than my version of Mathematica - thanks!

Comment: It's hard to choose, sometimes... :)

Comment: I think Yoda's is more general, and allows for finer control over styles.

Comment: And the styles need be specified just once, I suppose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll have to issue the opacity directive to `ColorFunction` like so:

```
a = ReliefPlot[
  Table[i + Sin[i^2 + j^2], {i, -4, 4, .03}, {j, -4, 4, .03}], 
  ImageSize -> 100]
b = ReliefPlot[
  Table[i + Sin[i^3 + j^3], {i, -4, 4, .03}, {j, -4, 4, .03}], 
  ImageSize -> 100, 
  ColorFunction -> (Directive[Opacity[0.5], 
      ColorData["Rainbow"][#]] &)]
Show[a, b]
```

[image]

In general, in all `*Plot*` functions, you control opacity with either `PlotStyle` or `ColorFunction`, as the case may be. If this were just a `Graphics` primitive, you'd probably do something like `Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], object}]`.

Answer (score 10):

Since `ReliefPlot` doesn't have a `PlotStyle` option, you can use `BaseStyle -> Opacity[0.5]` to introduce transparency into the graphics.

[image]

Comment: hold on... this works _only_ if both images have the same `BaseStyle`.

Comment: @yoda `BaseStyle` is an option to `Graphics`, so you get all the usual behaviors of how `Show` combines options from multiple graphics.  Now that I think about this for a moment more, you could just apply the `BaseStyle` option in the call to `Show`, rather than adding it to the individual plots.  Note that `BaseStyle` will apply to the entire graphic; not just the primitives from either `a` or `b`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was pointing out. If you wanted to overlay the second plot with 0.5 opacity on the first like in my answer, you cannot use `BaseStyle`...

Answer (score 10):

An alternative is to work with `Image`s and the [`ReliefImage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReliefImage.html) function, and then compose the resulting images together using `ImageCompose`:

```
ImageCompose[
 ReliefImage[Table[i + Sin[i^2 + j^2], {i, -4, 4, .03}, {j, -4, 4, .03}]],
 {ReliefImage[Table[i + Sin[i^3 + j^3], {i, -4, 4, .03}, {j, -4, 4, .03}]], 
  0.5}
 ]
```

[image]

Since `ReliefPlot` also essentially returns *pixel data* in a `Graphics`-compatible format, perhaps `Image`s will suit you better.

The default colour function of `ReliefImage` is different: you can use `ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"` to switch to `ReliefPlot`'s one.

<sub>Originally I had a function here to extract the raster data from `ReliefPlot`, but then Brett Champion pointed to `RasterImage` in the comment below</sub>

Comment: Assuming V8, you could also use `ReliefImage` instead of `ReliefPlot`, although then you have to reverse the input due to differences in coordinate systems, and there's also a different default color function.  (The default color function for ReliefImage is a bit dark for my tastes, but `ImageAdd[a,b]` looks decent.)

Comment: @Brett I was looking for that but couldn't find it!!  (Some Linux interfaces are really unwieldy and frustrating ...)  Will correct the answer.

Answer (score 7):

The answers using transparency will work in a very general way, but in this particular example of combining two ReliefPlot[]s, you might want to consider plotting the sum of the two:

```
f[i_] := i + Sin[i^2 + j^2];
g[i_] := i + Sin[i^3 + j^3];
ReliefPlot[Table[f[i] + g[i], {i, -4, 4, .03}, {j, -4, 4, .03}], ImageSize -> 100]
```

Comment: Thanks - it's a better solution in some ways! One of the good things about Mathematica is how it allows you to approach problems from various angles.

Answer (score 6):

```
Show[a, {Opacity[0.5],#}& /@ b]
```

Comment: +1. Alternatively, one can use `Show[a, {Opacity[0.5], #} & @@@ b]` with the same effect.

Comment: @jibe Which *Mathematica* version do you use? I just have checked both solutions with version 10.2 on Win7 x64 and the output is visually the same. Please check again starting from the code in the question.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov You're absolutely right. On Mac OS 10.8.5, with MMA 10.2, the examples of the OP with ReliefPlot does work. BUT, the test I made was with (contour) plots of my own and it did not work. Can you try to run this (without the `;`, but I don't manage to indent in the comments...) ?
`a = ContourPlot[Sin[x + y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
b = ContourPlot[Cos[x - y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
Show[a, {Opacity[0.5], #} & /@ b];
Show[a, {Opacity[0.5], #} & @@@ b];`

Comment: @jibe `ContourPlot` produces a `Graphics` expression with entirely different structure than `ReliefPlot`. You can see this structure by applying `InputForm` or by using my specially-designed [`shortInputForm` function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/280). The code in my comment was intended only for `ReliefPlot` and based on undocumented details of current implementation of `ReliefPlot` (which can be changed in future versions of *Mathematica*).

Comment: @jibe For `ContourPlot`s an analogous solution would be `Show[a, b] /. RGBColor[r_, g_, b_] :> RGBColor[r, g, b, .5]`, but its a kind of a hack which does not cover all the cases, so the straightforward solution would be to add `Opacity` via the `ContourShading` or `ColorFunction` option.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Many thanks for your answers. I checked that your second solution with `RGBColor` also works for me. Now the next step for me is to deal with the very buggy way `Opacity` and `Mesh` behave on Mac OS, when exported. (There are already a lot mma.se questions around about this subject!)